# Step-by-Step: Realistic Walking

Tags: animation, rigging

Meet [Iji](http://www.remar.se/daniel/iji.php). [image]

A cybernetic female teenager who single-handedly brought two alien species to the brink of extinction.

Now, she's kicking butt across the multiverse. Only problem is, I have forgotten how to make things walk realistically. She isn't using rigify, but has some bones pre-installed. Can someone walk me through the process of making her walk step by step please?

Comment: That is quite a process you're asking us to explain! Try looking at some blender animation tutorials

Comment: could you guys just close the question?! It's been answered already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a little basics on animating a walk cycle to get you started. There are four or six (depending on who you ask) key poses that make up a walk: 
[image]
This image shows each of these poses. After creating them about 3 or four frames apart you should have some realistic motion.

[image]