# How to make a usable walkcycle

Tags: animation

I'm trying to make a walk cycle on a character, but there's a problem. When I loop the walkcycle, the steps kind of ease in and out, making the feet slide even when the character is moving at a constant speed.

Could somebody please point out how to fix this issue? Is there a process to create a walkcycle that ensures that the feet move at a constant speed while they're on the ground?

EDIT This is different from the "duplicate" question in that I am not looking for a general answer on how to make a movement be steady, but *specifically* how to work with a walk cycle.

Comment: I think you're problem is related to the relationship between the first and last position of the cycle.  Did you copy the first position's key frames to the last position?

Comment: If you are trying to do a basic walk cycle, a good tutorial to start with is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFf5eGCjUUg

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33126/step-by-step-realistic-walking)

Comment: @MartyFouts If I understand you aright, then yes.